# Do solutions to the exercises in Preskill's lecture notes exist anywhere?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, resource-request

I'm teaching myself quantum computing and would like to know if solutions to the exercises in Preskill's lecture notes exist anywhere. It's quite hard to see if my approach is correct because I don't have a reference anywhere.